# Store HTML and dynamic PHP variables in MySQL table

Tags: php

I am currently able to save html in to a MySQL database and call that information when needed and all renders correctly.

However now i want to add dynmaic PHP variables also to the MySQL table along with the html, but when called from the database it displays as html/text and the PHP variables are no longer dynamic. Is this possible?

How can i store html and PHP variables, so they can be returned in the same way.

Please see my example, $ProfileName, $ProfileAge, $ProfileGender are my dynamic variables:

```
<div class="sampleheader">
    <div class="headerimage"><img src="/images/sample.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="headerprofilename">'.$ProfileName.'</div>
    <div class="headerprofileage">'.$ProfileAge.'</div>
    <div class="headerprofilegender">'.$ProfileGender.'</div>
</div>
```

Maybe I should return all as html and then use regex or str_replace to find ('.$ProfileName.', '.$ProfileAge.', '.$ProfileGender.') and somehome replace for the actual variables.

Any help is much appricated, thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you already storing raw html to the db? and want to store PHP vars into the db? What does your php code to store the data in the db look like, share that. And what do you mean by html variables?

Comment: Are you saying that this snippet of HTML is something you've stored in your database? Don't store raw PHP code in the database. You probably need to look at using some kind of templating engine. There are plenty available.

Comment: Clear answer: You can NOT store dynamic PHTML snippets in your database without any further useless effort. Did you ask yourself why nobody in the long history of PHP has done it yet? Yeah, right. It 's a bad idea. Just store PHTML files somewhere and include them as view in a controller, that has determined all your data in order to output your templates cleanly.

Comment: This is not a mysql problem, you need to either force the evaluation of the expression in the string (the html + php content is retrieved as string from the database) or you need to use some kind of a templating solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your text without concatenation. and store to database...

like below:

```html
    <div class="sampleheader">
        <div class="headerimage"><img src="/images/sample.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="headerprofilename">$ProfileName</div>
        <div class="headerprofileage">$ProfileAge</div>
        <div class="headerprofilegender">$ProfileGender</div>
    </div>
```

when you want show replace varibles like this:

```php
    $regex = "/\\$([a-zA-Z_]*)/m";
    $text  = '
    <div class="sampleheader">
        <div class="headerimage"><img src="/images/sample.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="headerprofilename">$ProfileName</div>
        <div class="headerprofileage">$ProfileAge</div>
        <div class="headerprofilegender">$ProfileGender</div>
    </div>
    ';

    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    // your variables
    $ProfileName   = 'Ali Sasani';
    $ProfileAge    = 28;
    $ProfileGender = 'man';
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if (isset(${$match[1]})){
            $text = str_replace($match[0], ${$match[1]}, $text);
        }

    }

    dd($text); // your final text
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, i am going to continue to play with this code.

Comment: Given this works for $Variables with a leading $, can this also be modified for Defined objects. i know you have matched on $ symbol, but can I for instance add a eading underscore to defined objects like _DEFINED_ITEM and match on that aswell as a $ symbol, but for leading underscore it knows its defined object, so removes the leading underscore. Hope that makes sense

Comment: hi, in regex pattern you can change it, `$regex = "/\\$([a-zA-Z_]*)/m";` , you can change `/\\$` to `/_` and add _ before latest slash ,
final pattern is `$regex = "/_([a-zA-Z_]*)_/m";`

Comment: I can not get this to work $regex = "/_([a-zA-Z_]*)_/m"; I have  define("FAVTEAMNAME", "Manchecter United");  so have $text  = '
<div class="sampleheader">
 <div class="headerprofilename">Name: $ProfileName</div>
 <div class="headerprofileage">Age: $ProfileAge</div>
 <div class="headerprofilegender">Gender:$ProfileGender</div>
 <div class="headerprofileteam">Team: _FAVTEAMNAME</div>
</div>
';

But its not replacing _FAVTEAMNAME with the defined FAVTEAMNAME.

Comment: Also, can i combine the both the regex $regex = "/\\$([a-zA-Z_]*)/m"; and $regex = "/_([a-zA-Z_]*)_/m"; so it will search the sting and replace anything $Variable or _DEFINEDITEM. Or do i need to run seperate?

Comment: run it seperatly... that has compex regex

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far, however, I can not get the underscore regex to work with the defined variables. Can you confirm the regex is correct: 

$regex = "/_([a-zA-Z_]*)_/m";
'
define("FAVTEAMNAME", "Manchecter United");

$text = '
<div class="sampleheader">
 <div class="headerprofileteam">Team: _FAVTEAMNAME</div>
</div>';

$regex = "/_([a-zA-Z_]*)_/m";

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
 if (isset(${$match[1]})){
  $text = str_replace($match[0], ${$match[1]}, $text);
 }
}
echo $text;'